# QueryStringField: When value is not specified

Tags: asp.net

I am using querystring for passing a value which is used to select the subscription category (variable name *subno*) on second page.

Based on the subscription category  (*subno* is specified as integer in sql server as part of table categories) second page is invoked using the following URL-

```
http://localhost:53175/v1/ProductsList.aspx?subno=1
or
http://localhost:53175/v1/ProductsList.aspx?subno=2
```

In the second page  *subno*  is used to query the items based on *subno* passed.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="subscription" runat="server"  
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aimnbde3ConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [subscription] FROM [subscription] WHERE ([subno] = @subno)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="subno" QueryStringField="subno" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This code works well if category(varibale subno) is passed.
In case second page is called directly like

```
http://localhost:53175/v1/ProductsList.aspx
```

Then value of subno is interpreted as 0. Do we have a way to change the query(SelectCommand="SELECT [subscription] FROM [subscription] ) based on value of subno ?

Or please suggest the right way to handle the case where subno is not passed

Editing -

Sorry for missing an important part of question-

When     `http://localhost:53175/v1/ProductsList.aspx`  is accessing i want to display all the products so the query will be

```
SELECT [subscription] FROM [subscription]
```

and in case a value is passed query will be

```
SELECT [subscription] FROM [subscription] WHERE ([subno] = @subno)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change the query to this:

```
SELECT [subscription] FROM [subscription] WHERE (@subno is null or [subno] = @subno)
```

and then add the following to the parameter

```
ConvertEmptyStringToNull = "TRUE"
```

and the following to the SQLDataSource

```
CancelSelectOnNullParameter = "FALSE"
```

So your code would look like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="subscription" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:aimnbde3ConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [subscription] FROM [subscription] WHERE (@subno is null or [subno] = @subno)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="subno" QueryStringField="subno" Type="Int32" ConvertEmptyStringToNull = "true"/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Thanks Graymatter for the quick reply -- please have a look on my updated question .. i want to display all the items when subno is not passed. sorry for the creating confusion

Comment: Seems  CancelSelectOnNullParameter is not part of library i am using -- here is the err- Error 66 Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryStringParameter' does not have a public property named 'CancelSelectOnNullParameter'. C:\aimnbde\v1\ProductsList.aspx 81

Answer (score 3):

You could simply change where part of SQL query to :

```
WHERE (@subno = 0 OR [subno] = @subno)
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio for the quick reply -- please have a look on my updated question .. i want to display all the items when subno is not passed. sorry for the confusion

Comment: if value of subno is intepreded as 0 when there are no params you will get all items

Comment: On using "WHERE (@subno = 0 OR [subno] = @subno)" for http://localhost:53175/v1/ProductsList.aspx i get no data is returned